# How to deploy Scheduling Policies in FSL from one environment to another?

Tags: field-service-lightning, fieldservice

I have created Scheduling Policy in my sandbox for FSL. How do I deploy it from Dev Sandbox to Integration sandbox and then to Staging and finally to Production? Is it a manual change or can we do it via changesets or Copado?

Any response would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From looking at [field service lightning Data model](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fs_standard_objects.htm&type=5), it seems Scheduling Policy are nothing but custom objects.

That means, its not metadata but just data. You should be able to use Salesforce DataLoader or Data Import Wizard.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Pranay. There is already one Scheduling Policy and I created the second one (am just 2 months old in this company). So, since there was one existing Scheduling Policy, can I still deploy via Data Loader or Data Import Wizard?

Comment: I cant see why you wont be able to

Comment: Ok. I will give it a shot :) Thank you so much.

Comment: @RituKhanna - you could also look at products like Gearset that allow for metadata AND data deployments

Comment: Thank you everyone for responding to me. It is truly appreciated.

Comment: @RituKhanna if it worked for you can you mark answer as accepted? It will allow other users with similar queries related to fls reach solution faster.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Sorry for the late revert. Yes, I will mark it as accepted.